# What's a twizzle?

Tags: terminology, olympics, ice-skating

My wife's made me watch a *lot* of ice dancing in the past, and have no recollection of any reference to a "twizzle".  This year, it seems like it's standard jargon that any enthusiast should know.

What exactly is a "twizzle"?

Answer (score 4):

A twizzle is when a skater executes a rotational turn with one foot while continuing to move across the ice simultaneously<sub>[(1)](http://sports.yahoo.com/blogs/olympics-fourth-place-medal/what-s-a-twizzle--here-s-a-guide-to-the-figure-skating-term-024737991.html)</sub>. This term is most common in ice dancing than other forms of ice skating.

Answer (score 3):

Twizzles need to be continuous in movement and in rotation. For instance in a single forward Twizzle, a skater would make a full rotation from forward to forward in either direction. The desired tracing on the ice would look like a tight double three turn (forward-backward-forward edge) and if the rotation would not be fluid it would be just this turn. In other words a Twizzle is a cross between a spin and a three turn. It is more fluid than consecutive three turns but neither centred nor loopy as a spin.